# Control the RGB tape with only one output of the microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm, rgb

I need to control the colors of an RGB ribbon. This requires 3 PWMs. But I have only one output of my microcontroller available. So for this I need to find a circuit that stays between the microcontroller and the RGB tape that allows me to change the colors receiving only a signal from the microcontroller (as in the image) I thought of an analog converter for PWM but I do not know how to do it or if it is possible.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBFz0k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: (Asynchronous) serial communication will do.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go with led driver like [WS2801](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2801.pdf) with external power switches. With which you will get very fine control over your strip with a 2-wire interface.

[image]

2. where as this driver [WS2811](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) which is a 1-wire interface.

Comment: This requires two outputs from the OP's microcontroller, but they only have one available.

Comment: The ic supports 1-wire ( 1 wire device communications bus system).

Comment: Can you clarify your comment, please? Where can I find information about using the WS2801 with a single communications wire?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson sorry edited my answer please check.

Comment: WS2811, one-wire interface with specific timing needs. https://www.adafruit.com has a library with the specific timing for Arduino boards.

Answer (score 2):

Use another microcontroller as your "intermediate circuit". Use the TX of a UART on your original microcontroller to send text commands to the RX pin of the new microcontroller. Define commands that set the PWM parameters for each channel. Program the new microcontroller to parse the commands and generate the PWM signals.

Comment: That's rather excessive and invokes unnecessary development when there are fixed function I2C, SPI, and unique interface solutions for this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Both I2C and SPI require more than one line from the microcontroller, which doesn't satisfy the OP's request. Furthermore, I didn't want to turn this into a recommendation for a specific product.

Comment: Actually what the question says is that they only have one *PWM* output available.  Also note that there are single wire LED data interfaces (the "unique" in the above comment), again available *off the shelf* without needing to do development and programming of an additional MCU.

Comment: 1-wire can be implemented for low-data rates with longer distances which is similar to I2C protocol

Comment: @ChrisStratton No, the OP states "But I have only **one output** of my microcontroller available." And I **still** don't want to recommend specific products.